# What is the exact function of a wireless router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

What does a wireless touter do? These usually are fed by an ethernet cable running from the modem that is plugged into a cable from the internet provider.

Comment: And do the ethernet ports of the router provide the same thing? Does the modem need to be password protected?

Comment: If it is on the same subnet as the main network, its only function is to provide a wireless radio. Fairly straightforward concept. You can use your wireless router as your main router because they normally have 4 or more Ethernet ports.

Answer (score 3):

A typical consumer grade "wireless router" is actually a multifunction device that provides the following services and functions:

- A WiFi access point, creating a wifi network
- A (typically) 4 port ethernet switch that also includes the wifi network
- A router that routes between your local network(s) and an external WAN network
- a NAT gateway, translating your internal local network addresses to a single external WAN ip address
- a firewall, blocking external incoming traffic, but configurable to allow some traffic, as well as UDP punch through
- a DHCP server providing support and automatic configuration for your local network

Some devices may also support other services such as print server, file server (both usually via USB), DNS cache server, time server.  These can be advertised to local clients and provided transparently via DHCP and zero config methods.